# Turning Point Cloud with vertex color and normal data into a Mesh using nodes?

Tags: node-editor, sverchok, photogrammetry

Not quite sure if this is a too big of a question to answer using Sverchok, but I will ask anyway: if we have Point Cloud data, each point has Color info and Normal info, how hard it is to turn it into a mesh whenever it finds triangles close to each other and generate mesh surface?

Kind of like a way to mesh construct point cloud data (NVM).

Comment: Look at the [cube surfer](https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer) addon. You can find info the algorithms from wikipedias [iso surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosurface#Implementation_Algorithms) page.

Comment: maybe it will produce useful answers if you ask this from a perspective of looking for dedicated add-ons or scripts. Turning it into a sverchok node/nodescript at that point would be trivial (but pointcloud data is, if big, not super suitable for an interactive use case of sverchok)

Comment: " how hard it is to turn it into a mesh " looks for a subjective answer. Maybe if you change that to "how would one approach this" and "this is what i've tried", and give some sample data -- at least that would invite some experimentation.

Comment: I realized that this question is pretty big and the answer can be using Metaballs, Marching Cubes algorithm, etc.